# Order a database with pandas with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following database structure:

| Column A | Vote1 | Vote2 | Size1 | Size2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item1 | 2 | -1 | 2.5 | 2.1 |
| Item2 | -3 | 3 | 2.2 | 3.3 |

I need to order the db by the multiply between Vote * Size, but I need to select the bigger between Vote1 and Vote2, same with Size1 and Size2.

> Bigger(Vote1, Vote2) * Bigger(Size1, Size2)

I'm having trouble undestanding how to this with pandas.

Comment: What database are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for all columns with `Vote`, get maximum and same way for `Size` column, last multiple Series:

```
df['new'] = df.filter(like='Vote').max(axis=1).mul(df.filter(like='Size').max(axis=1))
```

Or:

```
df['new'] = np.maximum(df['Vote1'], df['Vote2']) * np.maximum(df['Size1'], df['Size2'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Nice, so 'like' is selecting all columns that include the text you pass as argument I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to extract the column name before the number and use this for a [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html), then get the [`prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html):

```
df['product'] = (df.groupby(df.columns.str.extract('(\D+)\d+', expand=False),
                            axis=1)
                   .max().prod(axis=1)
                )
```

Output:

```
  Column A  Vote1  Vote2  Size1  Size2  product
0    Item1      2     -1    2.5    2.1      5.0
1    Item2     -3      3    2.2    3.3      9.9
```